# Can we write the part in bold like I wrote?

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation, literature

> All this – the house and the remnants of the pasture land, the seashore
> below the pale clay cliffs, the walk along it to the fishing village of
> Kilauran, the avenue over which the high branches of the chestnut trees
> now met – was as much part of Everard Gault as the features of his face
> were, **the family traits that quite resembled a few of those in the drawingroom
> portrait, the smooth dark hair. Tall and straight-backed, a man who
> hid nothing of himself, slight in his ambitions now, he had long ago
> accepted that his destiny was to keep in good heart what had been his
> inheritance**, to attract bees to his hives, to root up his failing apple trees
> and replace them. He swept the chimneys of his house himself, could
> repoint its mortar and replace its window glass. Creeping about on its roof,
> he repaired in the lead the small perforations that occurred from time to
> time, the Seccotine he squeezed into them effective for a while.

Can we write the part in bold like this:... **as the features of his face that he had inherited from his family and many of these traits were like those in the drawing room portrait and like the portrait he had smooth dark hair**. Tall and straight-backed, a man who hid nothing of himself, slight in his ambitions now, **he had long ago accepted that because of his destiny he should take care of his inheritance carefully.**

I searched  the meaning of "in good heart" and I found: Having a cheerful, hopeful, or optimistic outlook, demeanor, or frame of mind. But I think in this context we should write as I wrote.

Source: *The Story of Lucy Gault* by William Trevor

Comment: Yes, 'in good heart' does mean that when it describes a person. Here, it describes the house and land and means 'in a good condition'.

Comment: The expression "keep in good heart" today ***only*** means "stay upbeat / cheerful, do not despair" - and it's becoming a bit dated even with that sense. But a century or two ago it was commonly used to mean ***healthy*** (very often, as a ***figurative usage*** referring to keeping ***agricultural land*** "healthy and productive", by the regular application of manure, and other "land maintenance" activities).

Answer (score 0):

You want to say this:

> All this – the house and the remnants of the pasture land, the seashore below the pale clay cliffs, the walk along it to the fishing village of Kilauran, the avenue over which the high branches of the chestnut trees now met – was as much part of Everard Gault as the features of his face were, as the features of his face that he had inherited from his family and many of these traits was like those in the drawing room portrait and like the portrait he had smooth dark hair.

I'm sorry, but there are some things you need to fix first. First, **was** does not agree with **many** in number -- it needs to be plural **were**. Second, repeating *as the features of his face* isn't needed. Third, you're making the sentence far too long and too confusing. :o

In the second part, what you wrote is not a synonym for *keep in good heart*. What that sentence means is that he has resolved to **cheerfully** keep (up) his inheritance. The clauses that follow show how he is doing that.

Your research has shown what *in good heart* means, so I won't repeat that here.

Keep: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep

> b(1): to take care of : TEND
>
> keep a garden

Comment: I disagree about _keep in good heart_ - see my comment above.

Comment: That's cool; I'm glad you disagree.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your answer, I think "in good heart" hear means: in good condition as @Kate Bunting said. but was I right in interpreting the first part after corrections of @FelinliusRex? And I don't expect negative point for this question because I am learning english and I wanted to be sure if I am right in its interpreting or not.

Comment: Since you ask, my understanding is that the 'features of his face' which are 'part of' him include 'family traits' and 'smooth dark hair'. Are you sure _portrait_ isn't plural? I imagine a number of portraits hanging in the drawing room, several of which have features similar to his.

Comment: There is  just one portrait in the drawing room. A portrait of a distant family.

Comment: Your answer lacks focus.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Not only did I rewrite the paragraph for him, but I pointed out exactly what I did, and even quoted sources to back it up. I really don't see the lack of focus here, so please show me.